# Footer text appearing outside <body>

Tags: html, css

I have a standard set up for a web page of `<html><head></head>` followed by `<body></body></html>`. Within the `<body></body>` I have three sections, a `<header></header>`, a `<div></div>` to take the the text of each page and a `<footer></footer>`. All three sections have `display: block;` applied. The `<body>` is defined with a yellow background and a green border. The `<header>` and `<div>` sections appear within the green border, but the `<footer>` appears outside the green border. If I remove the `display: block;` definition, it appears inside the green border.

I did not expect that to happen.

EDIT - The problem in not when I remove the `display: block;`, it is when I include a `<div>` in the `<footer>`. The code in the `<div>` appears outside the `<body>`, the code in the footer itself appears inside the `<body>`.

Comment: do you have a html5 DTD at the top of the page?

Comment: Can you maybe post an example of your code at a site like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @Nicholas - I have <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"> at the top.

Comment: @veelen - This could take some time. I do not know how to use jsfiddle.

Comment: @veelen - What do you need to know to view it?

Comment: Your html and your css

Comment: @veelen - No, I meant what do you need to know to open it in jsFiddle?

Comment: @xiecs put the code in the fields, press run, hit save, copy url, paste url here.

Comment: The url is http://jsfiddle.net/xiecs/fM5Z5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an result of the  float you use on the footer > div. Floats make an element escape the page flow, and will therefore in this case be displayed outside the footer. You can either remove the float, or set the footer to a fixed height, so the child div will fit in.

Comment: Thanks - Fixed height it is.